# Using missing and exists filter together in single query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get a query which can return a json which satisfies both conditions of a filtering. I am trying to get a response which has feed containing one field named "test1" and it should also be missing a field "test2", Ive tried the query

```
{
 "query": {
  "filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
   },
      "filter": {
         "missing": {
        "field": "test2"
       },
       "exists": {
         "field": "test1"
       }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

The above query returns all the fields which has the field "test1" and it also returns feeds which are missing field "test2", I am trying to narrow down the response as I only want feeds satisfying both conditions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can combine two or more filters using [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "missing": {
              "field": "test2"
            }
          }, {
            "exists": {
              "field": "test1"
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```